# Android - Creating a static button, Not on the action bar, across Most activities

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a static button in my android app at the bottom of the screen.  The button will be on most of the screens / activities.  The button will have the same functionality across the app.  Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this?  It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to use an Activity with Fragments (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) or depending where you want your Button you can try Sherlock Action Bar (http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I needed a custom "ActionBar" so I created the `layout` for it and made it the `layout` for a `BaseActivity`. Then I `extends BaseActivity` in all of my other `Activities` which gives me the functionality inside all of them and the code is stored in the `BaseActivity` file.

Now, if I do need different functionality for one of the `View`s in a certain `Activity` then I `Override` that function in the `Activity` where it is needed.

I `<include>` the `layout` for `BaseActivity` in my other `Activities` xml files. You could do the same thing for your `Button`, which may be overkill but I'm not sure how else you will get this besides maybe using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)